# How can i create an query not using string?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i have to implement a query, not with string only i have to use hash like this

```
Products.where(:id != @product_id AND init_time <= ? AND (:section_id => @section_id OR :type_id => @type_id))
```

but i am getting errors in 'AND' 'OR' and how can i fix this part '!='?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can produce this query using `Hash` syntax alone but it is not as nice as I would like because you have to repeat conditions

For Example:

```
Products
  .where(section_id: @section_id, init_time: ..[YOUR INIT TIME HERE])
  .where.not(id: @product_id)
  .or( 
    Products
    .where(type_id: @type_id, init_time: ..[YOUR INIT TIME HERE])
    .where.not(id: @product_id)
)
```

as pointed out by [@3limin4t0r](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3982562/3limin4t0r) you could also use

```
Product
  .where(section_id: @section_id)
  .or(Product.where(type_id: @type_id))
  .where(init_time: ..@init_time).where.not(id: @product_id)
```

Which is definitely cleaner but this query is order dependent so the `where(condition1).or(condition2)` needs to be in the front of the chain to wrap the condition in parens appropriately.

Instead I would do so as follows:

```
Product.where.not(id: @product_id)
       .where(init_time: ..[YOUR INIT TIME HERE])
       .where( 
          Product.arel_table[:section_id].eq(@section_id).or(
            Product.arel_table[:type_id].eq(@type_id))
        )
```

Assuming

```
@product_id = 123
@section_id = 7
@type_id = 12
```

Both will produce:

```
SELECT 
  products.* 
FROM 
  products
WHERE 
  products.id != 123
  AND products.init_time <= [YOUR INIT TIME]
  AND (products.section_id = 7 OR products.type_id = 12)
```

Comment: You could simplify the initial codeblock by starting with the OR condition. `Product.where(section_id: @section_id).or(Product.where(type_id: @type_id)).where(init_time: ..@init_time).where.not(id: @product_id)`

Comment: Yes parentheses are set correctly. In my dummy environment (Ruby 3.2.0 & Rails 7.0.4.1) `Product.where(section_id: 1).or(Product.where(type_id: 2)).where(init_time: ..Time.now).where.not(id: 3)` results in `Product Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "products".* FROM "products" WHERE ("products"."section_id" = ? OR "products"."type_id" = ?) AND "products"."init_time" <= ? AND "products"."id" != ?  [["section_id", 1], ["type_id", 2], ["init_time", "2023-01-23 16:00:29.020986"], ["id", 3]]`

Comment: @3limin4t0r thank you for confirming because in the opposite order it did not (at least for me). That is slightly concerning and fragile to me which is why I have a tendency to reach for arel where possible given its consistency.

Comment: The opposite order does indeed yield a different result. If you look at the Rails query like this `Model.scope1.or(Model.scope2).scope3` Then records must match to either `scope1` or `scope2`, but they must always match `scope3`. If you place the `init_time` and `id` constraints before the `.or()` they will become part of `scope1`, meaning that they are optional if the record matches `scope2`.

Comment: this one please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75227985/how-can-i-create-a-query-but-it-does-not-have-to-repeat-the-same-value-many-time

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the above explanation of the query, but I would prefer a more compact query:

```rb
scope = Products.where(init_time: ..@your_time).where.not(id: @product_id)
scope.where(section_id: @section_id).or(scope.where(type_id: @type_id))
```

Comment: This is much cleaner although I am still not a huge fan of the syntax.

Comment: this one please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75227985/how-can-i-create-a-query-but-it-does-not-have-to-repeat-the-same-value-many-time